# Create enums or identifiers at runtime (potentially from JSON)

Tags: c++, json, enums, identifier

I wasn't sure how best to phrase my question here.

As part of a college assignment, I need to make a generic game component that has minimal impact on the client's codebase. I'm doing a quest management system, which relies heavily on type definition (quest/task/event types) that can then be used by the system. To give some important background info, the client will also need to define how these types are linked (i.e what events unlock a quest, which tasks make up a quest, etc.).

My dilemma is one of both performance and usability. Normally type identifiers are resolved using `enum`, however I can't expect this (potentially large) list of definitions to exist in the client's code, not to mention the other data that needs to be specified.

My first thoughts were to define these types as strings in external JSON files, but aside from the additional performance hit this incurs over `enum`, it means that the client developer must also verify that the `string` types they write match how they defined them. When using `enum` it is possible to bring up a list of them, as shown in image below, which gives the developer piece of mind that the type does in fact exist.

[image: Enum advantage]

My initial solution was to have string types and data in JSON files, and using macro functions, populate identifiers into a namespace with `integer` values (i.e mimic `enums`) and stringify the identifier so that it could be be linked with the JSON data.

```
// Creating identifier and stringifying it
#define ADD_QUEST(identifier) namespace QUEST_TYPES { int identifier = nextNumber(#identifier, 0); }

// Creating the quest identifiers
ADD_QUEST(COLLECT_10_COINS)
ADD_QUEST(SAVE_PRINCESS)

// Using the identifiers
questMgr.createQuest(QUEST_TYPES::SAVE_PRINCESS);
```

This solution is actually what's being shown in the image above, but it neglects the above rule of 'minimizing impact on the client's codebase.' As such it was turned down by my lecturer.

So I guess my question is, is there any way to populate enums/identifiers at runtime (possibly from, but not restricted to, JSON) or am I stuck with using string type identifiers for all my types?

Comment: enums don't really exist after compiling (identifiers are gone), so not really, no. It think the only thing you can do is to use an efficient structure to find the corresponding ID of a particular string, like a map<string, unsigned int>. In any case, even if somebody should come up with some macro magic or the like, readability is probably more important. Also, as for quests, it might be better to go with identifiers that are not numbers. Since one might want to add some quests in between later on. Maybe something like nation_place_name or chapter_faction_name as identifier?

Comment: @Aziuth: I had a feeling this would be the case. Even if identifiers could be created at run-time, the information cannot be brought up during development as it's not been created yet. I guess I was being hopeful that there might be some other solution. Using a map is probably the best option but it will still require developers to verify the identifiers they use. As for quest types, it looks like you're talking about nested ones. Thankfully I will not have to do that, but it's definitely worth thinking about.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with verification? Against what? Let's say I write "safe princess" instead of "save princess", from where should your program know that this is a mistake? If that is your JSON file, then this is simple, read in the file, create a map out of it and check whether that entry has a value or not (assuming that the map stores something like unsigned int ids).

Comment: You could wrap maps, like class Quests{private: map<...> data; public: unsigned int id_of_identifier(const string identifier){ map<..>.iterator i = data.find(identifier); if(i == data.end()){ cry_error(); } return *i;}}

Comment: Could you clarify the overall architecture in play here a bit? Who's the client?

Comment: @Aziuth: Yes, doing this with maps is no issue. It just means that the client (i.e developer using the component) will need to run the application to find out if there are any errors, which in a game may not be trivial. I was more looking to emulate enums (as seen in image) so that the client knows before building if any errors exist (thus increasing usability of the component).